# How to select join results into an array in mysql query?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a script that will export modx users to CSV, fairly straightforward stuff, but in modx users can belong to many groups. Simply joining the modx_member_groups table will result in several rows for different users.

What I would like to do is somehow rewrite the query below so that the join on the modx_member_groups would return a list or array of group ids that the user belongs to.

For example, I would like the returned data to look like:

```
user_group | id | username | ...the rest
1,3,5,7    | 12 | johndoe  | ...
```

here is the query I have.

```
SELECT mg.user_group, u.id, u.username, ua.*

FROM modx_users u 

LEFT JOIN modx_user_attributes ua ON u.id = ua.internalKey 

LEFT JOIN modx_member_groups mg ON u.id = mg.member

LIMIT 10
```

Ideally it would be awesome to somehow select the actual group names as columns. and then just force a true or false in the group name column.

**UPDATE**

I've updated the query after shtever's answer but have performance issues:
- GROUP_CONCAT was returning a BLOB type so I had to convert it, setting the group_concat_max_length to below 512 was not working

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(mg.user_group, CHAR(10)) ORDER BY mg.user_group SEPARATOR ',') AS groups, u.id, u.username, ua.*
FROM modx_users u 
LEFT JOIN modx_user_attributes ua ON u.id = ua.internalKey 
LEFT JOIN modx_member_groups mg ON mg.member = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

The query now takes 27.5 seconds to execute if I limit it to 10 results or let it run on the entire 6000 users it always takes 27.5 seconds. If I remove the GROUP_CONCAT ~ same amount of time.

Comment: Is this a MySQL database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For MySQL, take a look at the GROUP_CONCAT function.  [Mysql GROUP_CONCAT Description](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Your query might look something like:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mg.user_group ASC SEPARATOR ',') , u.id, u.username, ua.*
FROM modx_users u 
LEFT JOIN modx_user_attributes ua ON u.id = ua.internalKey 
LEFT JOIN modx_member_groups mg ON u.id = mg.member
GROUP BY u.id, u.username
LIMIT 10
```

You might have to fiddle with the GROUP BY fields depending on the relation between the modx_user_attributes and modx_users table.

Comment: Thanks - that does work, b ut I had to tweak it a little bit [see update]  I don't think I need the DISTINCT keyword as a user cannot belong to the same group twice, and it was returning a BLOB type [even if I set the group_concat_max_length] so I had to convert it.  However it is slow 27.5 seconds no matter what I do, with or without the CONVERT even if I remove the LIMIT, 10 records or 6000 records[there are 6000 users], it always takes 27.5 seconds!

Comment: indexing the member column in the modx_member_groups table solves the speed issue[queries under a second], but I'm not sure how that will affect the rest of the database?

Comment: Indexes occupy disk space and have to be maintained on inserts,updates,and deletes. In general, the overhead its worth it for the performance boost.